# How to center histogram bars?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am currently doing some analysis on Amazon's item ratings using pandas and matplotlib.

I am using the following code to generate a plot

```
result = ratings.copy()

result["rating"].plot(kind="hist")

fname = os.path.join("..", "figs", "my_figure.png")
plt.savefig(fname)
```

Where `ratings` is a dataframe that looks like this

```
0       A2VNYWOPJ13AFP  0981850006     5.0  1259798400
1       A20DWVV8HML3AW  0981850006     5.0  1371081600
2       A3RVP3YBYYOPRH  0981850006     5.0  1257984000
3       A28XY55TP3Q90O  0981850006     3.0  1314144000
4       A3VZW1BGUQO0V3  0981850006     3.0  1308268800
5       A2R9T5D7UVQZB0  0981850006     5.0  1253577600
6       A2MH49GAEWEI95  0981850006     5.0  1395532800
7        AR5DPX4ZU3D4Z  144072007X     1.0  1360886400
```

Unfortunately, my generated plot looks like this (notice how the bars are not all lined up)

[image]

#### How do I make it so that all the bars are centered (e.g. like 4.0 and 2.0)

Comment: It seems you only consider integers as possible outcomes. Hence you need to specify the histogram bins accordingly.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thats not my question. Even after specifying bins `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` the graph is still unaligned. Some bars are to the right of the axis, some to the left.

Comment: how about `result["rating"].hist(bins=5)`? if you provide a list, it takes those as the bin edges, and you need to make sure the integer ratings fall in-between the bin edges like so: `bins=[.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]`